# How to display called activity inside calling Fragment, as now it is hiding the main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I want to display Map View in a fragment, I'm achieving this by using startActivity(Intent), the Mapactivity is gettin started, but my main activity is in background. But i want to display that Map Activity in my calling fragment. How this can be achieved. Please help as soon as possible. I'm stuck..

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display Map View in a fragment

This is possible, but only using native fragments on API Level 11 and higher, and only by putting the `MapView` in an actual `Fragment`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkFragments

> I'm achieving this by using startActivity(Intent)

`startActivity()` has little to do with putting things in fragments.